# Calculations in Markdown (Python, Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm looking for solution to perform small calculations in text in Python Jupyter Notebook.

**for example:** 
What to add in this sentence

```
The difference between sth and sth is 32-11.
```

to have and effect

```
The difference between sth and sth is 21.
```

I know that in R this would be:

```
The difference between sth and sth is `r 32-11`.
```

Comment: Markdown is just static text; it cannot perform calculations.

Comment: Doing calculation on markdown is impossible but you can print out the values if that's sufficient ```print(f'The difference between sth and sth is {32-11}.')```

Comment: Jupyter notebooks can't mix code and plain text. To have a sentence print out and provide an answer you would need to create a code block as highlighted by @Jayakrishnan using the `print()` method to output the entire sentence along with the calculation. Although R can mix code and text on the same line. This isn't the case with Jupyter notebooks. Each block is dinstinct.